# requestFeature() must be called before adding content Android Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

Can't get this working, why am I getting "requestFeature() must be called before adding content"?

this is a Fragment.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expand, container, false);
        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.expand);

        getActivity().getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);



        ExpandList = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.exp_list);

        PD = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        PD.setMessage("Loading.....");
        PD.setCancelable(false);

        makejsonobjreq();

        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you calling the onCreate() super method within the onCreateView()? It will go back to the start? Can you remove that line of code and then post what you see?

Comment: Obviously remove anything that touches window from fragment. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Sunil I just did that, still getting the same error

Comment: @EugenPechanec I'm trying to edit my title bar in that particular fragment

Comment: Fragments don't have title bars at all. Activities don't have title bars since Android 3.0. How is the title supposed to look like? Let's find another approach.

Comment: Why are you setting the activity content view from the fragment? can you set the view for the activity within the activity itself?

Comment: Long story short: You don't EVER access views outside of a fragment from inside the said fragment. And from what I see you just copied some code from an activity to a fragment, which leads me to believe you don't need a fragment at all or at least have not the necessary understanding of fragments.